# A question about explicit computations of discrepancies

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, singularity-theory

The following is an explicit computation of discrepancies appeared in the book "Birational Geometry of Algebraic Varieties" (Page 126-127) in order to show certain type singularities are not Du Val. However, I did not get some details.

> Let $X:=\{(x^2+y^3+yz^5+z^7=0) \subset \mathbb C^3\}$ be a germ of singularity. Let $Y$ be defined as $$(p^2+q^3+qr+r=0).$$ Then $$\pi: (p,q,r) \mapsto (x=pr^3, y=qr^2, z=r)$$ gives a birational morphism $\pi: Y \to X$ with irreducible exceptional divisor $(r=0) \subset Y$. $Y$ is smooth at general points of $(r=0)$. A local generator of $\omega_X$ is given by $\frac{dy \wedge dz}{x}$. $$\pi^*\frac{dy \wedge dz}{x} = \frac 1 r \frac{dq \wedge dr}{p},$$ thus it has a pole along $r=0$ and $X$ is not canonical.

My questions are:

(1) Why the local generator of the canonical divsor $\omega_X$ is $\frac{dy \wedge dz}{x}$?

Notice that $X$ has singularity at $0$, so how to make sense of the local generator (why $\omega_X$ is Cartier), and why it is of the given form?

(2) How to see that "it has a pole along $r=0$ and $X$ is not canonical"?

This question boils down to find a local generator of $\omega_Y$ and compare it with $\pi^* \omega_X$. (The argument seems to suggest $\frac{dq \wedge dr}{p}$ is the local generator, then locally $\pi^* \omega_X = -E + \omega_Y$, where $E = (r=0)$, but the discrepancy is $1$ for $E$ according to my calculation. I must miss something...)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a hypersurface singularity $P\in X$ is defined by $(f=0)\subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ with local coordinates $x_0,\ldots, x_n$, then locally $\omega_X$ is generated by $$s=\frac{\mathrm{d} x_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x_n}{\partial f/\partial x_0}.$$
See for example, (1.8) of [M. Reid, Young Person's Guide to Canonical Singularities].

Hence in this case the generator of $\omega_X$ is $\frac{\mathrm{d}y \wedge \mathrm{d}z}{x}$ and the generator of $\omega_Y$ is$\frac{\mathrm{d}q \wedge \mathrm{d}r}{p}$.

For the second question, just note that $r$ is the generator of $\mathcal{O}_Y(-E)$ (not $\mathcal{O}_Y(E)$).

Comment: Thank you!! I agree with you at my second question. But for the first one, Reid wrote that the above expression is a local basis for smooth point, he also required $\partial f/ \partial x_0 \neq 0$. But here the origin is a singular point (I even don't know the Cartier index is $1$ or not). Moreover, for the smooth point, one can just choose $dx_1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ as a local basis because $\partial f/ \partial x_0 \neq 0$. But in the above case, one has to take into account of this term to get the correct result. Why?

Comment: In Reid's paper, $s$ is a generator on those points  $\partial f/ \partial x_0 \neq 0$, and then you can "extend" it to the singular point $Q$.

Comment: I don't think this could be done that simple: $dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ is also a local generator at smooth point, but the extension does not match the calculation...

Comment: Reid has explained clearly in his paper. In fact (1.8) contains a proof of why $s$ should be a generator. This is because that $s$ is invariant under change of coordinates. For example, if you change the positions of $x_0$ and $x_1$, then you will find that $\frac{\mathrm{d}x_0\wedge \mathrm{d}x_2\wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d}x_n}{\partial f/\partial x_1}=-s$ by the fact that $\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\mathrm{d}x_i =0$. This means that $s$ should be the correct generator of $\omega_X$.

Comment: On the other hand, $dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ is not invariant under permutation of coordinates on $X$, hence can not be a generator.